# singtool fails due to missing private key

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, signtool, digicert

I have a DigiCert EV Code Signing token used to sign code.
When I run `signtool` from a user shell, everything works fine.
However, when I run `signtool` from a system service it fails.

The last thing I tried was to "emulate" user shell, by doing:

```
$username = "USER"
$password = "PASS"
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "MYPC" -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock { signtool ... }
```

But this is fails as it doesn't find a private key...

```
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: MY Company
    Issued by: DigiCert EV Code Signing CA (SHA2)
    Expires:   Wed Mar 25 15:00:00 2021
    SHA1 hash: 1276675218A89930DD687B82559E27D0F5F89999
After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 0 certs were left.
SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.
```

Any ideas how can I proceed here?

It seems that a "remote user" doesn't have permissions to access the private key.

Comment: Export the certificate (with the private key), then import it into the system store?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen export with private key is missing as it's provided by the physical token

Comment: You can run a service with explicit credentials. Otherwise you could spawn the `signtool` process using `runas` with credentials.